# InputFile Mismatch Exception

Tags: java, exception

I can't get my code to read a file called pets.txt. I checked other similar questions but can't seem to find a solution. The error occurs when I try to read a line such that:

Name,1,1.2

the code here should output the name, age and weight of the pet found in pets.txt

```
 // import packages
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class Pets
{

    // throw exception if the file isn't found
    public static void main (String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        // Create a scanner objcct to read the file
        Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(new FileReader("pets.txt"));

        // Initiate objects and variables 
        PetRecord firstPet = null;
        PetRecord pet = null;
        PetRecord smallestPet = null;
        PetRecord largestPet = null;
        PetRecord oldestPet = null;
        PetRecord youngestPet = null;
        double age = 0, weight = 0;
        int counter = 0;

        if(fileReader.hasNext())
        {
            // Create a reference to compare values
            firstPet = new PetRecord();
            // Create a delimiter to find the pet data
            fileReader.useDelimiter(",");
            // Call accessors to set name and age in the file
            firstPet.setName(fileReader.next());
            firstPet.setAge(fileReader.nextInt());
            // Set a delimiter to read the next line
            fileReader.useDelimiter("[,\n]");
            // set the weight using weight accessor
            firstPet.setWeight(fileReader.nextDouble());

            // Print firstPet info
            System.out.println(firstPet);
            // Use pet1 to set values to be compared
            smallestPet = firstPet;
            largestPet = firstPet;
            oldestPet = firstPet;
            youngestPet = firstPet;

            // Increment counter
            counter++;

            // Add firstPet to age and weight total
            age += firstPet.getAge();
            weight += firstPet.getWeight();
        }

        // A while loop to read until there are no more lines
        while(fileReader.hasNext())
        {
            // Ctreate a new pet and read the data with the fileReader and delimiter
            pet = new PetRecord();
            pet.setName(fileReader.next());
            fileReader.useDelimiter(",");
            pet.setAge(fileReader.nextInt());
            fileReader.useDelimiter("[,\n]");
            pet.setWeight(fileReader.nextDouble());

            // Print the pets info
            System.out.println(pet);

            // if statement to find largest and smallest pet
            if(pet.getWeight() < smallestPet.getWeight()) 
                smallestPet = pet;
            if(pet.getWeight() > largestPet.getWeight()) 
                largestPet = pet;
            // if statment to find oldest and youngest
            if(pet.getAge() > oldestPet.getAge())
                oldestPet = pet;
            if(pet.getAge() < youngestPet.getAge())
                youngestPet = pet;
            // demonstrate use of equals
            if(pet.equals(firstPet))
                System.out.println(pet + " is equal to " + firstPet);


            // inctrement counter for each pet, keeping track of total
            counter++;
            // add each pets age and weight to the total 
            age += pet.getAge();
            weight += pet.getWeight();
        }

        // divide the age and weight by the counter to find the average of each
        age /= counter;
        weight /= counter;

        // Print the data
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Smallest Pet:\t" + smallestPet);
        System.out.println("Largest Pet:\t" + largestPet);
        System.out.println("Youngest Pet:\t" + youngestPet);
        System.out.println("Oldest Pet:\t" + oldestPet);
        System.out.println("Average Age:\t" + age + " years");
        System.out.println("Average Weight:\t" + weight + "lb");


        fileReader.close();

    }

}
```

Instead I get an input Mismatch exception at the first line of the text file. I'm reading a String, an int, and then a double so not sure where the mismatch occurs....I double checked to make sure the file is saved in the same project folder and it is.

edit: the errors are as follows:

```
exception java.util.fileInputMismatch at:
java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Unknown Source)
at Pets.Main(Pets.java:37)
```

edit: here is pets.txt

```
Barney,5,12.6
Frenchy,3,43.5
Marcus,4,54.2
Gilbert,12,4.6
Milley,2,7.4
```

Comment: Do you get the mismatch when calling `nextDouble()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a quick-fix, you can put instead of `fileReader.nextDouble()` -> `Double.valueOf(fileReader.next())`.

I haven't managed to figure out yet why this occurs. I am checking and will edit my answer. Cheers!

**Later edit:** the problem is due to the fact that `Scanner` is using the wrong locale. To fix your issue all you have to do after creating the `Scanner` is `fileReader.useLocale(Locale.US)`.

A working sample:

```
Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(new FileReader("pets.txt"));
    fileReader.useLocale(Locale.US);

    double age = 0, weight = 0;
    int counter = 0;

    // A while loop to read until there are no more lines
    while(fileReader.hasNext()) {
        fileReader.useDelimiter(",");
        System.out.println(fileReader.next());
        System.out.println(fileReader.nextInt());
        fileReader.useDelimiter(Pattern.compile("[\\r\\n,]+"));
        System.out.println(fileReader.nextDouble());

    }

    fileReader.close();
```

And my pets.txt file is exactly the one you gave as an example.

Hope it helps!

Comment: well I did add the locale just now and it still gives me the same errors :( it ws good thinking though

Comment: Edited my answer. The issue was that I was trying with only one line in pets.txt. When I entered more than one line, there was an issue with the pattern defined in `useDelimiter()`. Updated that to `Pattern.compile("[\\r\\n,]+")` and everything worked as expected. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your help! This is for a beginning java class though and I don't think we have learned the Pattern class yet. This answer works though...how do I accept an answer here (sorry super new to stackoverflow)

Comment: There is a checkmark on the left side of the answer which you have to tick. You can read more here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Actually, if you don't want to use the `Pattern`, you can just do `useDelimiter("[\r\n,]+")`. Should work, haven't tested though.